# User can only see his data Django

Tags: python, django

Im building a contract management system, and i want to the user to only the companies, clients and users that he registered, now when i register a new user, he can also see the data companies that other users registered.

How can i make it see only his own clients, companies and contracts?

**views.py**

```
# List the companies
@login_required
def client_company_list(request):
    clients = ClientCompany.objects.all()
    pending_payments_total = ClientCompany.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('pending_payments'))['sum'] or 0
    received_payments_total = ClientCompany.objects.aggregate(sum=Sum('received_payments'))['sum'] or 0
    client_count = ClientCompany.objects.filter().count()
    return render(request, 'list_client_company.html', {'clients': clients,
                                                       'pending_payments_total': pending_payments_total,
                                                       'received_payments_total': received_payments_total,
                                                       'client_count': client_count})

# Crate a new company
@login_required
def new_client_company(request):
    # Start post add the company to the DB using POST or start a new form using None
    form = ClientCompanyForm(request.POST, request.FILES, None)

    # Check if the form is valid
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return redirect('companies_list')
    return render(request, 'client_company_form.html', {'form': form})
```

**models.py**

```
# Company client
class ClientCompany(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    company_cnpj = models.IntegerField()
    phone = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    email = models.EmailField(null=True, blank=True)
    pending_payments = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    received_payments = models.DecimalField(blank=True, null=True, max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)

    # To return the name of the company on the django admin
    def __str__(self):
        return self.company_name


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
    # Create standard user
    def create_user(self, email, full_name, password=None, is_active=True, is_staff=False, is_admin=False):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('User must have an email address')
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError('User must provide a full name')
        if not password:
            raise ValueError('User must provide a password')
        user_obj = self.model(
            email = self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name = full_name
        )
        user_obj.set_password(password) # Defined user password
        user_obj.staff = is_staff
        user_obj.admin = is_admin
        user_obj.active = is_active
        user_obj.set_password(password) # Defined user password
        user_obj.save(using=self._db) # Defined user password
        return user_obj

    # Create a staff user
    def create_staff_user(self, email, full_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name=full_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True
        )
        return user

    # Create superuser
    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name, password=None):
        user = self.create_user(
            email,
            full_name=full_name,
            password=password,
            is_staff=True,
            is_admin=True
        )
        return user


# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)  # If active can login
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # If the user is a staff member
    admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)  # If the user has superuser permissions
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # Get the time that the user has been created
    #confirm = models.BooleanField(defaul=False) # Confirmed email
    #confirmed_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True) # Get the time that the email has been confirmed

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'    # That is now the username
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']    # Email, name and password are required

    objects = UserManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email

    def get_full_name(self): # Return the name of the user
        return self.full_name

    # def get_short_name(self):
    #     return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return True
    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True

    # Check if is staff
    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        return self.staff

    # Check if is admin
    @property
    def is_admin(self):
        return self.admin

    # Check if is active
    @property
    def is_active(self):
        return self.active
```

Comment: What is the rule that tells you which user registered a company? Does the company object store that information? Or does the user object keep track of which companies were registered? Or is it represented in a database somewhere, or something else? You can only perform calculations with data that you actually have. It looks like you showed us code to give the user a submission form for new company information; but what do you then do when the form is submitted? Presumably, you make the new company, and you *know* at that point in the code which user was responsible, but how do you *remember*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the relation between a user and his/her company somewhere, so you can filter accordingly in the view.

The classic approach is to create a Profile model for that, which would connect User and Company. Or if you are using your own User model (looks like it) then you can simple add a FK to the company to the User model.